# React-native Expo multiple image upload not working

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm currently writing an app where users can upload images, but I want users to be able to upload multiple images.

I've tried using libraries like:
expo-image-picker-multiple,
expo-images-picker

but nothing seems to be working.
I would love to know which library can I use to allow users to upload  when using expo [react-native]

### **UPDATE**

expo-images-picker implementation

```
     <AssetsSelector
        options={{
          assetTypes: ['photo'],
          noAssetsText: "No media found",
          maxSelections: 3,
          margin: 2,
          portraitCols: 4,
          landscapeCols: 5,
          widgetWidth: 100,
          widgetBgColor: "#fff",
          selectedIcon: {
            Component: Ionicons,
            iconName: "ios-checkmark-circle-outline",
            color: "#fff",
            bg: "#000",
            size: 25
          },
          noAssets: {
            Component: () => <Text>No assets</Text>
          }
        }}
      />
```

returns error 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Settings.portraitCols')

I've been getting this error while trying to implement expo-images-picker. How can I fix this?

Thanks,
Arnav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem - it works fine when `allowsMultipleSelection: false`, but setting it to `allowsMultipleSelection: true` gives an error ( `"code":"ERR_INVALID_MEDIA_TYPE","message":"Cannot handle 'public.jpeg' media type"` for every picture I try to select)

I left an issue here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/19300, I hope it gets picked up

Context:
React 18
Expo SDK 46
Expo-image-picker": “~13.3.1”,
iOS 15.5 Iphone Simulator
Typescript 4.8.2

Answer (score 0):

"expo-images-picker" is an updated library with full Platform Compatibility, it should work, it's the best way for that. You may have forgotten to allow the permissions required to make it work.

Comment: Thank you @Wallace Nascimento I've just changed my question a little bit to include my expo-images-picker implementation <but it is resulting in an error>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).